# the space on the right side of a site made with Bootsrap is not going away?

Tags: html, css, containers, grid-system

the white space on the right side of a site I made with Bootsrap did not go away no matter what I did. If there is a solution, please let me know

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contact | Enba Camping</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


            <!-- NAV -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 p-0">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary p-0 ">
                            <div class="container-fluid bg-dark ">
                                <a class="navbar-brand text-light mb-2" href="index.html">Enba   Camping</a>
                                <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-light btn btn-outline-light bg-light m-2"
                                    type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                                    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                                    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                                        
                                        <a class="nav-link  text-light text-center" aria-current="page"
                                            href="index.html">Home</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link text-light text-center" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link active text-light text-center" href="contact.html"
                                            aria-disabled="true">Contact</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- NAV END -->

            <!-- ABOUT US -->
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 ps-0">
                        <img src="images/lesly-derksen-F4fH5dAfZnE-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class=" d-block w-100 c-img ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h2 class="fw-bold display-4 ">Bize Ulaşın</h2>
<!-- ABOUT US -->

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Adınız</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                    placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email Adres</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                    placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Mesajınız</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" placeholder="Message"
                                    rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" gap-2 d-md-block ">
                                <button class="btn btn-light " type="button">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ABOUT US END -->

            <!-- PRODUCT -->

            <div class="container mt-sm-5">
                <div class="row text-center ">
                    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Mekanlarımız</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/card2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Orman İçi Karavan Parkı</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Ormanın içinde konumlanan karavan parkımız, tam anlamıyla bir doğa
                                    kaçamağı
                                    sunuyor. Ormanın huzurlu atmosferinde kendinizi kaybedin. Karavanınızla konforlu bir
                                    konaklama deneyimi yaşayın.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Rezervasyon için tıklayınız </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/card3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Orman İçi Çadırlı Kamp</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Orman içi çadırlı kamp alanımız, doğa severler için bir cennet.
                                    Gölgeli
                                    ağaçlar arasında konumlanan çadırlarımızda, kuş cıvıltıları ve huzur içinde bir
                                    konaklama
                                    deneyimi sizi bekliyor.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Rezervasyon için tıklayınız</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/card1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Dağ Evi </h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Dağ evimiz, şehrin gürültüsünden uzak,huzurlu bir konaklama imkanı
                                    sunuyor.
                                    Ferah odalarımızda dağ manzarasının keyfini çıkarabilir, gölet kenarındaki
                                    aktivitelerle
                                    vakit geçirebilirsiniz.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Rezervasyon için tıklayınız</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- PRODUCT END -->

            <!-- PROJECT -->

            <div class="row my-4">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Galeri</h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/hichem-meghachou-7I-Rj_E9ihI-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/jimmy-conover-J_XuXX9m0KM-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/josh-campbell-UbbjVyibFuc-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/shelby-cohron-ESNV6KmLJMg-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/tegan-mierle-fDostElVhN8-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm col-6 mb-1"><img src="images/galeri/toa-heftiba-x9I-6yoXrXE-unsplash.jpg" alt=""
                        class="w-100 img-thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>

          

            <!-- PROJECT END -->

            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <div class="bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="container">
                    <footer class="pt-5 mt-5 ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3">
                                <h5>Section</h5>
                                <ul class="nav flex-column ">
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Features</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Pricing</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">FAQs</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">About</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3">
                                <h5>Section</h5>
                                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Features</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Pricing</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">FAQs</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">About</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6 col-md-2 mb-3">
                                <h5>Section</h5>
                                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Features</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">Pricing</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">FAQs</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-light">About</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 mb-3">
                                <form>
                                    <h4>
                                        Abone Ol ve Doğanın Güzelliklerini Kaçırma!</h4>
                                    <p class="fs-6">Doğanın kucaklayıcı atmosferine adım atmak, huzurla dolu anlar
                                        yaşamak ve
                                        Enba Camping'in sunduğu özel fırsatları kaçırmamak için hemen abone ol! Sitemize
                                        abone
                                        olarak, doğanın gizemli güzellikleri, özel indirimler ve etkinliklerden ilk sen
                                        haberdar
                                        olacaksın.</p>
                                    <p class="fs-6">
                                        Unutulmaz anılar biriktirmek ve doğanın kollarında huzurlu bir deneyim yaşamak
                                        için
                                        abone ol, Enba Camping'in eşsiz dünyasına adımını at! ️✨
                                    </p>


                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row w-100 gap-2">
                                        <label for="newsletter1" class="visually-hidden">Email address</label>
                                        <input id="newsletter1" type="text" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Email address">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Subscribe</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between border-top">
                            <p>© 2023 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
                                <li class="ms-3"><a class="link-body-emphasis" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24"
                                            height="24">
                                            <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
                                        </svg></a></li>
                                <li class="ms-3"><a class="link-body-emphasis" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24"
                                            height="24">
                                            <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
                                        </svg></a></li>
                                <li class="ms-3"><a class="link-body-emphasis" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24"
                                            height="24">
                                            <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
                                        </svg></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- FOOTER END -->

</body>

</html>
```

and CSS

```
.jumb
{
vertical-align: inherit;

}
p
{
 font-size: 24px;
 
}

.c-item
{
    height: 480px;
}
.c-img
{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter:brightness(0.9)

}
```

[enter image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP6dd.jpg) here. I didn't want the page to be left and right. I want to make it fit full screen but the container structure is overflowing

Comment: that space is the scrollbar! It is a control element of the browser not your website! Why should it "go away"?

Comment: please remove this class "container mt-sm-5"

Comment: after check and ping ,me

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this piece of code to your CSS file. Then, it will work.
`.row{ margin-right: 0px; }`